# Ubuntu -> Win 10: pass a linux variable to the win file explorer

Tags: linux, windows-10, bash, windows-explorer

I'm trying to pass a linux variable as a part of a file path to explorer.exe. The shellscript (bash) I use is the following:

```
!/bin/sh

pdflatex $Name.tex

explorer.exe "C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Korrespondenz"
```

After running the `pdflatex` command the file explorer should open the specified folder `C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Korrespondenz\$Name` and show it in a window in the front. The script works except the last part containing the Linux variable.

How can I change a Linux variable into a Windows variable to pass it to the explorer.exe command?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm a little confused; you say "The script works except the last part containing the linux variable."  Nowhere in your code you've provided here do you tell Explorer to use ANY variable.

Comment: The variable I mean comes from a user input from another shellscript and is called $Name - just like I wrote: "C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Korrespondenz\$Name". You're right - the variable isn't in the code yet ...

Comment: Ok so you actually tried `explorer.exe "C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Korrespondenz\$Name"`?